# Jquery table pagination with filters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pagination, filtering

Stackoverflow! I have html table with filter buttons and simple navigation (next / prev).

I've found a simple filter code. It works fine:

```
$('#filter button').on('click', function() {
  $('table tr').hide();
  $('tr.' + $(this).attr('class') + '').show();
  if ($(this).attr('class') == 'showall') $('table tr').show();
})
```

And another one for pagination. It also works fine:

```
    /* Variable Defaults */
var total    = $('tbody > tr').length;
var position = $('tbody').data('position');
var jump     = $('tbody').data('jump');
var paginate = function(position, jump) {
    
    /* Show Default Items */
    $('tbody > tr').each(function() {
        /* Variable Defaults */
        var index = $(this).index();
        
        /* Condition */
        var condition = (index >= position) && (index < position + jump);

        /* Hide/Show Item */
        $(this).toggle(condition);

        /* Set Disabled Status */
        $('.less').prop('disabled', (position - jump) < 0);
        $('.more').prop('disabled', (position + jump) >= total);
    });
};

/* Set Default Text */
$('.count').text(jump);

/* Init Paginate */
paginate(position, jump);

/* Bind Click Events to "Less" and "More" Button */
$('.less, .more').on('click', function() {
    /* Decrease/Increase Position */
    position = $(this).hasClass('less') ? $('tbody').data('position') - jump : $('tbody').data('position') + jump;

    /* Paginate */
    paginate(position, jump);

    /* Update Position */
    $('tbody').data('position', position);
    
});
```

**But if I use filter code it ruins the pagination, and vice versa.**

How can I make them work together?
[Here's JSFIDDLE Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4w9nq5c1/)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that `$('tbody > tr').each(function() {` is for each tr. and not the hidden or showed ones.

I would save the clicked button `var active_button = $(this);`
and then for each result compare if results are within this triggered button :)